# How to connect light fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

I’m changing a light fixture, and I didn’t think to check how the old one was connected, but it was connected to the red and the pink wires shown in the picture attached, just don’t know which ones were connected to which ones. The black and white (tan) wires were tucked away.

The new light fixture has only a black
wire, a white wire and a ground copper wire.

How should I connect them to the set of wires in the photo.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Should change the red to a white if needed, since the red is connected to white(neutral).  The pink goes to black of the light.

Comment: A larger photo striaight into the box with the focus on the box would also help here.

Answer (score 2):

Without actually checking things this could be wrong, (if someone did things wrong in the past, mostly) but if you're sure the fixture attached to the two free single wires: Probably fixture white to the group of white attached to one of the red wires (I can't see a red/pink difference there, just two red wires with white paint slopped around) removing that red wire, and fixture black to the other red wire. If you need more length there, use a section of white wire, not red, for that.

Fixture bare (or green) (Ground) to the group of bare wires, which appear to need an actual wirenut rather than merely being twisted together, but perhaps there's one out of sight.

If you have a meter could check a few things (such as voltage from each of those wires to ground with the switch off, and voltage from each wire to ground with the switch on) to be more sure. Likewise voltage from group of blacks to ground.